# Automatic installation of rosbridge_library

Tags: catkin, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm working on a ROS Package that includes various dependencies, including Python libraries like ws4py and bson, as well as the ROS Package **rosbridge_library**. I've managed to configure CMakeLists.txt and package.xml to install the Python dependencies no problem, but for the life of me I can't get catkin_make to install rosbridge_library.

If I manually install the dependency with

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rosbridge-server
```

then catkin_make, my code works fine. If not, I get:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "rosbridge_library"
  with any of the following names:

    rosbridge_libraryConfig.cmake
    rosbridge_library-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "rosbridge_library" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "rosbridge_library_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "rosbridge_library" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

But I was under the impression that if I defined the dependency correctly then catkin_make should automatically download and install rosbridge_library without me having to do it manually. Now I'm starting to doubt it! Am I correct?

I'm using CircleCI to build on a new machine every time. Here is the exact sequence that I run:

```
 sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-base
 sudo rosdep init
 rosdep update
 echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
    
 mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src && cd ~/catkin_ws/src && catkin_init_workspace
 mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src/luxagent && cp -r ~/luxagent/* ~/catkin_ws/src/luxagent
 pip install 'gevent==1.0.2'
 echo "export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:${PYTHONPATH}" >> ~/.bashrc
 cd ~/catkin_ws/ && catkin_make
```

If after, the first block of commands I run

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rosbridge-server
```

then it all works fine.

Here are the relevant lines in package.xml:

```
  <build_depend>python-catkin-pkg</build_depend> 
  <build_depend>rosgraph</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>python-gevent</build_depend>
  <build_depend>python-ws4py-pip</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rosbridge_library</build_depend>

  <run_depend>python-catkin-pkg</run_depend> 
  <run_depend>rosgraph</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>python-gevent</run_depend>
  <run_depend>python-ws4py-pip</run_depend>
  <run_depend>python-bson</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rosbridge_library</run_depend>
```

Here are the relevant lines in CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rosbridge_library
  rosgraph
  raspy
)
```

and

```
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES luxagent
   CATKIN_DEPENDS rosgraph rospy rosbridge_library
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

I've tried substituting rosbridge_suite for rosbridge_library but the effect is the same. I would love to make the installation of this library automatic for the end user.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Thanks

Simon

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233374/automatic-installation-of-rosbridge_library/) by [SimonB](https://answers.ros.org/users/21874/simonb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2016-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> But I was under the impression that if I defined the dependency correctly then catkin_make should automatically download and install rosbridge_library without me having to do it manually. Now I'm starting to doubt it! Am I correct?

No, that is not correct. *Installing* dependencies is `rosdep`s responsibility. *Finding* dependencies is `catkin`s task.

I don't see a

```
rosdep install --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws --ignore-src
```

anywhere in the sequence of commands that you listed. You should add it before trying to `catkin_make` your workspace.

---

Edit: also, for *Python-only* projects, you don't actually need any of your Python libraries / components listed as `COMPONENTS` in your `find_package(catkin REQUIRED ..)` command. Python libraries are not `build_depends`, so you should not try to find them at build/configuration time.

Unless of course there are some native parts in them that need to get build, but I don't have any direct experience with that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SimonB](https://answers.ros.org/users/21874/simonb/) on 2016-05-01**:
That worked! Thanks so much! Every time I think I've got a handle on what Catkin does, I find I'm still in the dark. Your comment has cleared it up, at least for now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-05-02**:
catkin == cmake (more or less). CMake doesn't install any dependencies either. For some more howto-like documentation on it, see [catkin 0.6.18 documentation](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/).